# Should sugar cereal waste any time defending themselves?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, physical

*Defending themselves*: When the back cover of the cereal has the main purpose of convincing people their cereal is full of nutrition, but still tasty.

**Honey Nut Cheerios**

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

They are trying to convince us that Honey Nut Cheerios is full of "Irresistible Taste" and "Good Nutrition."

**Corn Pops**

[image: #2 Visual Aid]

The back of the Corn Pops package says:

> ... for a taste that makes kids smile on the OUTSIDE while they get
>   more of the good stuff they need on the INSIDE.

This helps make the claim that they are delicious and fun, while also being healthy. They also show the process of how Corn Pops are made. To continue, they use the phrase:

> An irresistible touch of sweetness.

This phrase helps imply that only a minimal amount of sweetness is added and that the rest is nutrition.

**These two boxes of cereal are defending themselves by trying to establish a balance between sugar and nutrition.**

---

What about those companies that don't give a crap and try to be as fun as possible?

**Captain Crunch**

[image: #3 Visual Aid]

**Chocolate Toast Crunch**

[image: #4 Visual Aid]

Captain Crunch and Chocolate Toast Crunch clearly don't care about defending themselves. Instead, they want to be as fun as possible.

---

**Is there any research on companies clearly using untrue claims to impress customers?**

Comment: That's a lot of questions about a lot of opinions. Chances are this question isn't going to go anywhere productive. I'd suggest slicing it down to a narrower question about the psychological technique of using clearly untrue claims to woo users.

Comment: @plainclothes I agree with you. I was asking too my questions. I have edited my original post to narrow it down. Does this look good? If so, would you mind removing your close vote?

Comment: What can I do to not make this question so broad?

Comment: Well, I wasn't suggesting that a direct quote of my comment was adequate to make a decent question. As asked it's just a general issue about persuasive arguments and the psychology of vice. But I'll retract my vote and see where it goes.

Comment: What research are you looking for, or more to the point, what information or data are you trying to obtain? Tobacco companies have been doing this for many years, and I don't know that there's any laws or regulations that will stop them (this is where ethics and moral values come into play).